# Where can I find thorough DCOM documentation?

Tags: windows, security, rpc, dcom

I work on an application that uses DCOM to communicate between what are essentially several peers; in the course of normal use, instances on separate machines serve a variety of objects to one another.  Historically, for this to work we have used some magic incantations, chief among which is that on every machine the user must log into an account of the same name (note that these are local accounts; there is no domain available).  Obviously, this is an aspect of our user experience that could be improved.

I would like to better understand how DCOM authentication works, but I am having difficulty assembling the whole story from the MSDN documentation for [CoInitializeSecurity()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693736.aspx), [CoSetProxyBlanket()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692692.aspx), and the like.  Are there any thorough explanations available of how, exactly, DCOM operations are accepted or denied?  Books, journals, web, any format is fine.

Comment: Why does this question have the xml-rpc tag?  DCOM doesn't have anything to do with XML-RPC except that both are RPC methods.

Comment: That is a good question; it appears to have been drive-by retagged (I originally tagged it "windows, security, dcom, rpc").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Programming Windows Security* by Keith Brown includes a thorough discussion of DCOM security. I can highly recommend this book.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to round up a copy of *Inside Distributed COM* by Guy and Henry Eddon (Microsoft Press) - It is out of print but amazon shows a number of used copies for sale:

[http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Distributed-Com-Mps-Eddon/dp/157231849X/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1231968553&sr=8-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231849X)